# PHP website not running exec function when passing image as an argument

Tags: php, c++, arguments, exec, exe

I'm having trouble running the "exec" function in my PHP website. I am able to run it several times with an executable that just takes in a variable argument and returns some test message. However, when I use an executable that does some image processing, where I want to pass an image from the website that a user uploads as an argument, it does not seem to be executing the executable at all. I even have some cout commands in the executable to ensure its running, but these are not being displayed on the website. So I think that for some reason the php cannot run the executable? I am able to run it fine from my desktop...

Here's an example of the code that isn't working on my PHP website:

```
$imgtest1="/uploaded_files/me.jpg";
$imgtest2="/uploaded_files/clusteroutput.jpg";
$nosuppix = 400;
$noweight = 100;
$executabletest = exec("ImgProc $imgtest1 $nosuppix $noweight $imgtest2");
echo $executabletest;
```

Is there a way to debug or get an error output from the exec function? Is there something I'm missing when passing an image to the executable? The executable uses several DLL files which are in the same folder as the executable. Do they need to be packaged together for some reason? I apologize, but I really don't know what's left to test...

***Edit: I'm now able to get it to run if I write out all the code in the escapeshellcmd itself... how come I'm not able to just pass the variables?

```
$cmdinput = escapeshellcmd('SuperpixelsFinal "D:/WebPages/TALIA ART/TALIA ART/uploaded_files/me.jpg" 400 100 "D:/WebPages/TALIA ART/TALIA ART/uploaded_files/clusteroutput.jpg"');
```

Comment: your missing the quotes. `$executabletest = exec("ImgProc \"$imgtest1\" $nosuppix $noweight \"$imgtest2\"");`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, it is because I was using escapeshellcmd when I should have used escapeshellarg for each individual string and then run the exec with double quotes using only variables like so:
$executabletest = exec("SuperpixelsFinal $imgtest1 $nosuppix $noweight $imgtest2");